# Question about the definition of a submanifold.

Tags: differential-geometry, submanifold

defintion (smooth manifold): A smooth manifold M is a topological manifold with an maximal atlas of compatible charts $(U_i, \psi_i)_{i \in I}$.

definition (submanifold): A $n$-dimensional submanifold is a  subset  $\tilde{M} \subset M$ of a smooth $k$-dimensional manifold M such that for each $p \in \tilde{M}$ there exist a chart $(U,\psi)$ of $M$ with $p \in U$ and $$\psi(\tilde{M} \cap U)=V \cap (\mathbb{R}^n \cap \{0\}) \subset \mathbb{R}^k$$

($V=\psi(U)$).

question: Does the chart $(U,\psi)$ has to be an element of the maximal atlas or just any chart of $M$? And if it could be any chart, does then even exist for each $p \in \tilde{M}$ a chart in the maximal atlas with the properties above?

Comment: By definition of maximality, a chart of a manifold is part of its maximum atlas.

Comment: @DIdier_ A the maximal atlas only is maximal regarding all compatible charts. So maybe we just have a chart that is not compatible to all charts in the maximal atlas

Comment: I mean, a manifold is a topological spaces with a maximal atlas. When working on a manifold, once we say "take a chart", this means "take a chart in the atlas of the manifold". Otherwise, this does not make any sense to require for a manifold to have an atlas.

Comment: It has to be a chart that lies in the atlas. Any other chart is not compatible with the notion of smoothness on $M$.

Comment: Ok thank you for your answers!